# Provision a Storage Account with JAVA client

Tags: java, provisioning, azure-storage-account

I need to provision an Azure Storage Account programmatically, preferably using a Java client. After spending some time looking for available Java libraries, I found libs that provide already existing storage management capabilities. I suspect no lib allows me to provision it programmatically.

Any ideas will be appreciated